# Wcf Service not caching with Castle ActiveRecord

Tags: c#, mysql, wcf, caching, activerecord

I've created a Wcf service using a MySQL database and Castle ActiveRecord.  The service will be called individually a number of times from different 3rd Party applications.  I'm wanting the Wcf service to cache all frequently used data, rather than making repeated trips to the database.

I've set the Wcf service to run as a single

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IConfigurationSource oSource = ActiveRecordSectionHandler.Instance
    ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize(oSource, typeof(MyObject));
}
```

Then in one my Wcf methods, I have the following to retrieve the data from the ORM

```
using (new SessionScope())
{
        List<MyObject> oObjectList = MyObject.FindAll().ToList();
}
```

My object is set as follows;

```
[ActiveRecord(Lazy = true)]
public class MyObject : ActiveRecordBase<MyObject >
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }

    [Property]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

}
```

The problem I have, is when doing a simple read to request the data like

> MyObject.FindAll().ToList()

, the database is being queried every time, rather than the cached data being returned, since the data in database is unchanged.

Where am I going wrong...?

Comment: You haven't implemented any caching in your code right?

Comment: No not at the moment, I was of the understanding ActiveRecord would offer some by default and I could use a Single instance of Wcf

Comment: Have you tried :
using(new SessionScope(FlushAction.Never))

Comment: Yes I tried that, but still if I query the database, and make the same call to service it is querying the database, even though the data remains unchanged